# Jar created through eclipse on windows is Working but Getting failed on linux

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a jar file which includes the dependencies of JSOUP library also . It is working fine in my system but when i put it on the Linux machine still it is displaying my o/p but after that it is displaying the below error.

```
  #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000003d3a26a040, pid=31443, tid=140607474837248
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-mockbuild_2014_04_09_11_51-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000003d3a26a040
#
```

Comment: If i am running a jar file without any dependency on the linux machine it is working fine there.

Comment: This is a native Java crash. Very strange as jsoup has as far as I know no native part. How did you create your jar, and what does "includes" mean? Can you try your jar without the dependencies included and add jsoup.jar on the classpath?

Comment: I am using eclipse and did the following steps.  Export-Runnable jar -Extract required libraries int generated jar and Finish. I used Winscp to put to Linux and from there i am running through java - jar <jar name>   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-182 ~]$ java -jar Testing.jar
Enter Model Name :

Comment: I am getting the required o/p but after displaying the o/p it is showing that Fatal error

Comment: A java core dump must be somewhere on your system with a name similar to `hs_err_pid21178.log`. There you can find more information about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEV means that your program is producing a so called segmentation fault

**Signal Description**

SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGPIPE, SIGILL -- Used in the implementation for implicit null check, and so forth.

Most of the segmentation fault error I have seen are reported on linux machines running OpenJDK . So if you can please install oracle jdk on the machine and see if it works.

**If you cannot install oracle jdk then first enable core dump .**

To enable core dump use `"ulimit -c unlimited"`

please refer links below for more info on enabling core dumps

http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_enable_core.html

http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_enable_core-dumps

with core dump Please go through the links below which shows various steps taken to resolve this issue. Plz not this could also be a jvm issue and hence may need to be reported as a bug.

https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/issues/detail?id=136

http://www.postseek.com/meta/cb1a8a97e39165b3f4f598114ec4889a

[Java fatal error SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101142/java-fatal-error-sigsegv)

[Java Runtime Environment SIGSEGV error on server startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943993/java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-error-on-server-startup)

[Debugging SIGSEGV Java Fatal Error in libjvm.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365646/debugging-sigsegv-java-fatal-error-in-libjvm-so)

[JVM Crash due to SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403852/jvm-crash-due-to-sigsegv)

**Below links will give you a better understanding of the issue**

http://fusionsecurity.blogspot.in/2011/10/why-am-i-seeing-sigsegv-when-i-strace.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/crashes-137240.html