# Elasticsearch crashes without error message

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a problem with elastic-search. After some minutes of starting elastic-search, it crashes without any error message.

```
Java Version: jdk1.8.0_45
Elastic-search Version: 1.4.5
```

I'll attach my java crash log (http://pastebin.com/NN9PHWU4).

Does anybody has an idea what the issue is, and how I can fix it?

Thanks,
Marcel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging SIGSEGV Java Fatal Error in libjvm.so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365646/debugging-sigsegv-java-fatal-error-in-libjvm-so)

Comment: you log report link in invalid.

Comment: Wich link do you mean ?